# What is the best way to store Clients in Serversocket

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air

for an installation with multiple mobile phones and computers, i need to implement a socketserver which handles communication between the devices.
For example: Phone 1 wants to make computer 3 play a sound. 
When the computer is done playing that sound it sends a message to the phone. 
Now in the server i need to make sure that the connection payloads get delivered to the correct recipient.
For now i have an array with all the socket references in it.
When a phone sends the message to the computer the server looks up the socket corresponding to the recipient of the message by comparing the IPs of the message target and the sockets stored in the array to find the correct recipient.

```
var target_ip:String="192.168.2.25"
var payload:String="hello!"
for each (var sock:Socket in _clientSockets){
    if(sock.localAddress==target_ip){
        sock.writeUTFBytes(payload);
        sock.flush();
        break
    }    
}
```

Is there a more elegant version to do this? 
Should I maybe store the sockets in a dictionary or similar?
Thanks for all tips!

Comment: Yes, a Dictionary would be better. But you need some unique identification as a dictionary key. I'm not sure about IPs, the clients might be connected from the same subnetwork or behind a proxy, so they will have the same external IP? I don't know how it works in this case, just want to make note about this. You'll also need a second (reverse) Dictionary where keys will be sockets themselves. For example, you need to close a socket and remove it from Dictionary, but you don't know its identification, do you look it up in the reverse Dictionary using socket as key.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I wanted to use only one object to store verything. So i was thinking about an array with objects. {sock:Socket, id:UDID} so i can search on the key for either socket or id...

Comment: Of course an array can be used, but if you have many sockets, the communication will be slower. I.e. each time you need to send something, you will have to do a search loop and thus users will experience some lag. With Dictionary it will take constant time no matter how many sockets are open.

Comment: Ah. I see thanks. In my project, there will be max 16 Clients ( Fixed installation ).